# Android sqlite database get id from list view

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview, listadapter

I have a database from work that i placed in my assets folder I use a listview to show some elements and then i need to click on a row to make it display more information, it works maybe my code sucks but i does what i need, but now they asked me to put a search box to look for specific items and its not working because i used the position on the listview to know what item was clicked and now when i use the search box the position and id change.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView datos;
ListAdapter adapter;
SQLiteConnector sqlConnect;
EditText search;
TextView _id;
ListAdapter intento;

SQLiteHelper dbTools = new SQLiteHelper (this);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    datos = (ListView)  findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    sqlConnect = new SQLiteConnector(this);
    search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextbuscar);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sqlConnect.getAllRecord());
    datos.setAdapter(adapter);


    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {




        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            ((Filterable) MainActivity.this.adapter).getFilter().filter(cs);

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        }

    });

    datos.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


        long posicion = (id + 1);

        String fraccionValues = String.valueOf(posicion);

        Intent detailsint = new Intent(getApplication(), Details.class);

        detailsint.putExtra("_id", fraccionValues);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), fraccionValues + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        startActivity(detailsint);

        }       

    });

}
```

}

I need a different way to identify the items on the list, this is the code of the activity that is called after the click

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.details_activity);
    Fraccion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewfraccion);
    Descripcion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewdescripcion);
    ADV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewadv);


    Intent theIntent = getIntent();

    String _id = theIntent.getStringExtra("_id");

    HashMap<String, String> fraccionMap = dbtools.getFraccionInfo(_id);

    if(fraccionMap.size()!=0) {

        Fraccion.setText(fraccionMap.get("fraccion"));
        Descripcion.setText(fraccionMap.get("descripcion"));
        ADV.setText(fraccionMap.get("adv"));

    }

}
```

}

Someone told me to use id insted of position but it gives me the same result and they told that it was because i did not include the _id in my db but i did.

Please help me i'm on an internship and i need to get this to work, this job will help me get a lot of experience to go to college prepared.

this is the sqlite connector

```
public SQLiteConnector (Context context) {
    sqlHelper = new SQLiteHelper (context) ;

}

public List<String> getAllRecord() {
List<String> fraccionesList = new ArrayList<String>();
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_RECORD + " ORDER BY _id"; //+ " WHERE COLUMN = Fraccion";

database = sqlHelper.getReadableDatabase();
cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        fraccionesList.add(cursor.getString(1));
    }

    while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }

database.close();
return fraccionesList;

}
```

}

and the sqliteopenhelper

public class SQLiteHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
private static String DB_PATH="/data/data/com.as.sqliteviewer/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME="Tarifa.s3db";
private static int VERSION = 1;
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private final Context myContext;

public SQLiteHelper (Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    myContext = context;
    try {
        createDatabase();
        }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error ("Unable to create database");

    }
}

public void createDatabase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
        System.out.println ("DB EXIST");
    }

    else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        this.close();
        copyDataBase();

    }
}

public void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte [1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);

    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }
    catch (SQLiteException e) {
        System.out.println("Database doesn't exist yet.");
    }

    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (myDataBase  != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public HashMap<String, String> getFraccionInfo(String id) {
    HashMap<String, String> fraccionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM fracciones WHERE _id ='" + id + "'";

    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            fraccionMap.put("_id", cursor.getString(0));
            fraccionMap.put("fraccion", cursor.getString(1));
            fraccionMap.put("descripcion", cursor.getString(2));
            fraccionMap.put("adv", cursor.getString(3));

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
return fraccionMap;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use setTag() and give the View/position/id you want a unique tag.  I use this with some shopping cart things - tag a view with an item's catalog number, or sku, and then I don't have to remember which position/id the user clicked - I merely getTag() of the view

edit:

If you want to set a tag, that's easy:

```
 someView.setTag(someValue);
```

In my custom listview, I set the tag of each item within getView()

```
someView.setTag(value_dereived_from_position);
```

Then, in other parts of my code, I might be responding to a click or button press. I can interrogate the view and check the tag:

```
Object index = some_other_view.getTag();
if (index == expected_value) {
   // do something 
}
```

Comment: can you give an example using settag ?

Comment: i would need to automatically give a tag to all of the items from the database (thousands)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the query in getFraccionInfo from SQLiteOpenHelper

```
public HashMap<String, String> getFraccionInfo(String id) {
    HashMap<String, String> fraccionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery ="SELECT * FROM fracciones WHERE fraccion = '" + id + "'";

    //String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM fracciones WHERE _id ='" + id + "'";

    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            fraccionMap.put("_id", cursor.getString(0));
            fraccionMap.put("fraccion", cursor.getString(1));
            fraccionMap.put("descripcion", cursor.getString(2));
            fraccionMap.put("adv", cursor.getString(3));

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
return fraccionMap;
}
```

}

And in my main activity i get the text that is displayed in the view  with

```
String fraccionValues = ((TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).getText().toString();
```

now the query uses the text of the view the "fraccion" to look for the other info from my database.

I have pictures but i cant upload them because of my reputation.

I have a blog i will upload the pictures there

[Blog](http://tech7811.blogspot.mx/)